# Google Distance Matrix API Key Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, api-key, google-distancematrix-api

I can't get the VBA Code in my Excel Document to connect to my account, using the API Key.  Not sure if I'm putting the key in the right place.  I've even upgraded my account, and have billing Enabled.  I'm trying to pay them, but it wont let me exceed 2,500 transactions.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit (7/20):
So I updated my code to use ClientID instead of API key '&clientid=EntersIDHere' and it works, but still only does 2500 transactions.

```
'Calculate Google Maps distance between two addresses
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=en-US&clientid=EntersKeyHere"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

Comment: `sensor=key=EntersKeyHere` that doesn't make sense (even assuming you anonymised your key)

Comment: What doesn't make sense?  If i take out the 'sensor=' it doesn't calculate.  It calculates with it in.

Comment: parameters should be separated by '&' right now you have a parameter named sensor which equals "key=EntersKeyHere" instead of having a parameter named sensor equal to "" and a parameter named key equal to "EntersKeyHere". And thats what does not make sense

Comment: I updated code using ' lastVal = "&mode=car&language=en-US&sensor=""&key=EntersKeyHere" '
but doesn't calculate

Comment: You should remove the "" or else sensor will be equal to " "" ". Or just remove sensor completly

Comment: So I updated my code to use ClientID instead of API key '&clientid=EntersIDHere' and it works, but still only does 2500 transactions

Comment: according to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/?hl=en) exemple from google, it should be `key` but maybe you have to pass both for it to work?