# My VBA code is not using my Google Distance Matrix API key

Tags: vba, excel, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

**EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION**

I've copied and tweaked some code to connect to the Google Distance Matrix API and I'm having issues going over the free limit.

I have an account and my key has 100K per day enabled, so I'm not sure exactly what the issue is.  This will work for single pulls up to the free limit of 2500 but then return error messages that tell me I've hit the limit.

```
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
    origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=en&ClientID=[INSERTKEYHERE]"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Url = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

I have also used key=[INSERTKEYHERE], but that didn't seem to fix the issue, and even made the function not work.  This question was asked here as well, but never publicly resolved.  [Google Distance Matrix API Key Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485353/google-distance-matrix-api-key-excel-vba)

Thanks!

Comment: `my guess is that the &clientid=[INSERTKEYHERE] is not being added on to the URL` ..... why don't you know the value of the `Url` variable ??

Comment: The URL variable is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
    origins="Referenced Address+City+State+Zip Code"&destinations="Referenced Address+City+State+Zip Code"&mode=car&language=en&ClientID=[INSERTKEYHERE]

The code is pulling my distances fine up until the 2500 free cap.  I have paid for the premium level, however, my API key is showing no queries, and I can't pull up to the 100K limit of the premium level.

Comment: I added that as an "I hope I didn't make a stupid mistake that's costed me hours of research," not as an "I don't know how to make URL's."  

I figured an easy fix would be "too easy" but didn't want to discount my human-ness.  I'll take it out so others can move past it to help me.

Comment: You need to make sure you URL encode each URL parameter (each parameter on its own). Use application.encodeurl() function instead of replacing. Also the URL variable you provided has a space before 'origins' and double quotes after origins=

Comment: What happens if you read and follow the [Add the API key to your application](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key?hl=en#step-2-add-the-api-key-to-your-application) versus [Authenticating your application using a client ID and digital signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key?hl=en#client-id)?

Comment: Other than that, the server may need you to set further request headers

Comment: the space before `origins` looks bad

Comment: i did not say that you do not know how to make a URL. i was talking about the `Url` variable that is used in `objHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False` .... if you print it, then there is no `i guess` .... simply put `debug.print url` just before the `objHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False` and look in the `immediate window` for the printout ... you can then copy the url and paste it into a web browser to check its validity

Comment: To Axel - I tried replacing clientID with Key like the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key?hl=en#step-2-add-the-api-key-to-your-application says. It broke the function and pulled errors.

Comment: To jsotola - I am sorry I took offense, I have been tasked with getting this done in a few hours so my nerves are a little shot.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Brandon Horrar: Then what you have possibly is not a api key but really a client id? So read my second link?

Comment: @BrandonHorrar, please do an inquiry in a web browser, if you get a valid response, then copy the url, scramble the api key so that it stays secret, and post the url here

Comment: To Jsotola - no the 39 digit code is actually in that space. To axel - I used the API key generator to get that code, and I didn't receive the email to generate the base64signature, that they mention.  But I did set up a paid account at night, maybe I'll receive a confirmation email in the morning?

Comment: are you sure that you do not have a space after `json?` .... the code that you posted is badly formatted at `firstval = ...`

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%222750+Pine+Street,+Suite+D+Arkadelphia,+AR,+71923%22&destinations=%2214136+Baxter+Dr.+Baxter,+MN,+56425%22&mode=car&language=en&Key=xxxxx

Comment: this is why we don't code past 4am.... I didn't use https in the URL generator.... thank you for the debug.print tool I will be sure to use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was twofold.  I was using Client ID instead of Key, which made the API give me the free version, and I didn't use https and was thus blocked out.

SOLVED